# linux iptables wrong line

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have next **/etc/sysconfig/iptables** rules (default setting after instalation):

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [92:28264]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

After adding a role like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

should at this point port 80 be open?
After I save iptables like this:

```
service iptables save
```

I get

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [92:28264]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Which does not work, I wold expect a new rule to be one line higher, what do you think?
I am using centOS. Also, what is the best practice here, should I just change the file and restart the iptables, is that better?
 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` you must restart iptables:

```
/etc/init.t/iptables restart
```

OR

```
service iptables restart
```

But when you write iptables commands in bash you must do:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

OR

```
service iptables save
```

Try to modify `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file to:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT --protocol icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp --protocol tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp --protocol tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

This is also correct to enter iptables commands in bash:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

If you are using debian based or any distro this is recommended to enter iptables command in bash(terminal) because `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` is just exsisted in **redhat** based distros...

## UPDATE

If you want to run iptables command in bash terminal it is better to remove your rules first...You can run this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

iptables -F
iptables -X

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Comment: I know I must restart if I change the file itself, but do I have to restart if I use command line like "iptables -A INPUT -m s..."

Comment: no..If you restart in such way your command would be removed...just you should `save` it...

Comment: That is all fine, because I did use save after using command line, bit it still did not work. Can you please help me understand why? Do I must use "INPUT 4" to put the command in the correct line?

Comment: Try this one:`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Sorry, but I am not thrill about multiport. One, not more please. I have tried any way , but it does not work. Thanks

Comment: running this bash should solve your problem...The order of running ruls are really important..So this is better to remove and flush previous rules

Comment: tried your "previous comment" but did not work. I do not have to use save right, it should effect immediately?

Comment: just check my simple bash script please

Comment: just check my simple bash script please I added to my asnwer, running this bash should solve your problem...The order of running ruls are really important..So this is better to remove and flush previous rules

Comment: update works, but I am not too happy about rewriting all the roles . Maybe I should just edit a file itself and restart the  service? How does that sound? Or is that a bad practice.

Comment: This is recommended to have copy all times from your commands and if you want to be sure you are doing correct configuration iptables run script again, But why your previous command is not correct? this is because the order of commands, As our friend said you must put them in order by using some commands like `-I INPUT 4`

Comment: yes, order is important. But is it ok to just edit the file itself and restart the service or it is a bad practice? Thanks

Comment: This is not bad practice, But this useless in other distros...You can use `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` only on `redhat based` distros like `centos`

Comment: You are welcome...You can mark some of my useful comments for knowing other guys... Have a nice time :)

Answer (score 0):

`-A INPUT` means append to chain INPUT, so the rule goes on the end.  You want `-I INPUT 4` to insert the rule into the chain before the REJECT rule.

Comment: Thanks, but why 4? How do I know what number?

Comment: That will make it the 4th rule.  You can put it anywhere before reject, but its more efficient to put the most-used rules first.